# When using discord.py purge with slash commands: i can only delete 1 message or i get an error

Tags: python, discord.py, command, slash, purge

I can delete one message or else i get this error message in discord: "The application did not respond"

Or this error message in the console: "discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'clear' raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction"

This is my code(**the purge command, which causes problems, is in the last shown file**):

**src/**init**.py:**

```
import os

import discord
from discord.ext import commands as discord_commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from src import commands


def run_discord_bot():
    def get_token():
        load_dotenv()
        return os.environ.get("TOKEN")

    token = get_token()
    intents = discord.Intents.all()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = discord_commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", intents=intents)

    commands.await_commands(client)

    client.run(token)
```

**src/commands/**init**.py:**

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands

from src.commands import responses


def await_commands(client):

    # syncing slash commands
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        try:
            synced = await client.tree.sync()
            print(f"Synced {len(synced)} commands(s)")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    @client.tree.command(name='clear', description="Delete messages")
        @app_commands.describe(amount="Number of messages to delete")
        async def clear(interaction: discord.Interaction, amount: int):
            await responses.clear(interaction, 'clear', amount)
```

**src/commands/responses.py:**

```
async def clear(interaction, command, amount: int):

    if amount > 100:
        await message(interaction, command, f"The amount of messages to delete is too much", True)
    elif amount > 0:
        await interaction.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        await message(interaction, command, f"{amount} messages have been deleted", True)
    elif amount < 0:
        await message(interaction, command, f"Can't delete a negative amount of messages", True)
    else:
        await message(interaction, command, f"0 Messages have been deleted", True)
```

I already tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work.
I just want to use slash commands to delete any amount of messages in a channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Application does not respond" simply means that your bot does not respond to the command after 3 seconds (while you are purging messages), and you must answer the command within 3 seconds. Therefore, if the `amount` is bigger, the purging takes longer time (more than 3 seconds), which will cause this message to appear. 
The solution is quite simple by `defer` the interaction first and send a `followup` after you finished purging all messages.
Some idea:

```py
async def clear(interaction, command, amount: int):
  # if amount is between 0 and 100, defer first and purge
  if 0 < amount <= 100:
    await interaction.response.defer()
    # purge the messages
    await interaction.followup.send(content="purge finished.")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
I had to write: await interaction.response.defer(), but i figured it out and it finally works.

Comment: oh yeah. Sorry for the typo